# TableRow within TableLayout's content out of screen

Tags: android, tableview, tablerow

This problem is pretty simple, I think.

The thing is: My TextView (Which is in a TableRow which is in a TableLayout) gets out of the visible screen.

A screenshot should clarify:

[image: yep]

I tried

```
        tvValue.setLinksClickable(true);
        tvValue.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MIDDLE);
```

1) No truncation is applied
2) Obviously, they show links, but they are not clickable!

As its a highly dynamic thing i need to do all initialization in code.
So, here's the code:

```
public class StartUp extends Activity {

private TableLayout mTableLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Context appContext = getApplicationContext();

    mTableLayout = new TableLayout(appContext);
    mTableLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);

    String[] h = new String[] { "email", "facebook", "youtube" };
    String[] v = new String[] { "lol@xd.de", "http://www.facebook.com/010101010101010", "http://www.youtube.com/lalala" };

    LayoutParams rowLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for (int i = 0; i < h.length; ++i) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(appContext);
        row.setLayoutParams(rowLayoutParams);

        TextView tvHead = new TextView(appContext);
        tvHead.setTextColor(0xff336699);
        tvHead.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
        tvHead.setText(h[i]);

        TextView tvValue = new TextView(appContext);
        tvValue.setTextColor(0xff191919);
        tvValue.setLinksClickable(true);
        tvValue.setText(v[i]);
        tvValue.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MIDDLE);


        row.addView(tvHead);
        row.addView(tvValue);
        mTableLayout.addView(row);
    }

    setContentView(mTableLayout);

}
```

}

Comment: share xml code .2nd thing is  its good to set maximum properties in xml layout itself .

Comment: BTW, If you want the setEllipsize part to work, don't forget to request focus for the textView. It will only work if the view has focus!

Comment: @Entreco Isn't this a real problem then? Assuming only one view can have focus, what if around 5 TextView's need to be ellipsized?

Comment: you can put those 5 views in a viewgroup, and request focus for the viewgroup. Than you need to make sure that the focus is passed through to the viewgroup's children

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setColumnShrinkable()?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#setColumnShrinkable%28int,%20boolean%29

Comment: Adding a simple mTableLayout.setColumnShrinkable(1, true); right the line before setContentView(...) does the job. Thanks!